# Find journal approval date in General Ledger Oracle Fusion 20c

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, oracle-fusion-apps

How can I find journal approval date in General Ledger Oracle Fusion 20c

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I Found ansver. Join GL_JE_HEADERS join to GL_JE_ACTION_LOG